# How to show validation error message for custom validation in angular4 reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular-validation

In component I have created form using form builder:
For contact Number feild I have added validation mobRegex and I want to show msg when pattern does not match.

**Component snippet:**

```
createForm(): void {
    this.contactUsForm = this.fb.group({
        'name': ['', Validators.required],
        'email': ['', Validators.compose([
            Validators.required,
          //  Validators.pattern(this.emailRegex)])],
            Validators.email])],
        'queryType': [null, Validators.required],
        // 'date': ['', Validators.compose([ValidationService.spaceValidator, Validators.required])],
        //'subject': ['', Validators.required],
        'subject': ['', Validators.compose([
          Validators.required,
          Validators.maxLength(100)])],
       // 'message': ['', Validators.required],
        'message': ['', Validators.compose([
          Validators.required,
          Validators.maxLength(1024)])],
        'contactNumber': ['', Validators.compose([
          Validators.required,
          Validators.pattern(this.mobRegx)])]
    });
//     if (this.queries.selected.type.toLowerCase() == 'schedule-a-call')
//         this.contactUsForm.addControl('timeSlot', new FormControl('timeSlot', Validators.required);
}
```

In html I have contact field and markup is as below:

```
<div class="form-group">

  <input
  type="text"
  class="form-control input-lg"
  id="contactNumberInput"
  placeholder="Contact Number"
  formControlName="contactNumber"
  [formControl]=" contactUsForm.controls['contactNumber']"
  [(ngModel)]="support.contactNumber"
  required>


<div *ngIf="contactUsForm.get('contactNumber').touched && 
contactUsForm.get('contactNumber').invalid">
<div *ngIf="contactUsForm.get('contactNumber').hasError('required')">
   Contact Number is requied
 </div>
<div *ngIf="contactUsForm.get('contactNumber').hasError(mobRegx)">
  Contact Number should be a valid phone number  // This part is not working
</div>
```

I want to show an error msg when mobRegx does not match.

> mobRegx = /^(+\d{1,3}[- ]?)?\d{10}$/;

Also can some one refer me some good article I can find built in rules/patterns for angular reactive forms?

Comment: Found a way:
 <div *ngIf="contactUsForm.get('contactNumber').hasError('pattern')">
                                        Contact Number should be a valid phone number
                                    </div>

Thanks to https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-introduction/

Answer (score 3):

You Can find all the guidelines about the validations and usage of the reactive form from the following tutorial

https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

and for applying pattern you can use validators.pattern()

https://angular.io/api/forms/PatternValidator
for ex-

```
Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z]+$');
```

Comment: Thanks for help @komalpreet singh! :)